# Document root Apache 2 não consegue encontrar rotas do laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Partindo do pressuposto que estamos em um servidor linux temos o seguinte senário.

o document root apontado para

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public
ServerName site.com.br
```

daí temos uma problemática pois o framework não consegue encontrar as rotas definas no arquivo routes.php penso eu que isso é devido ao document root estar apontando para a pasta public daí a partir daí ele não encontra as rotas www.site.com/rota alguém teria uma solução para isso, caso seja mesmo esse problema.

Comment: Experimente adicionar esta linha: DirectoryIndex index.php

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema esteja ocorrendo porque você não habilitou a opção de *override* na sua configuração.

Tente deixar o Virtual Host assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.com.br
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">
    AllowOverride all
    DirectoryIndex index.php
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Verifique também se na pasta *public* do seu projeto existe um arquivo chamado *.htaccess*, o conteúdo padrão deste arquivo no Laravel é o seguinte:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Habilitar o mod_rewrite do apache2 também caso ele esteja desabilitado.